# Profit and Loss : Manufacturer

Tags: arithmetic

A manufacturer undertakes to supply **2000 pieces** of a particular component at    **Rs.25 per piece**. According to its estimates, even **if 5% fail** to pass the quality tests, then he will make a **profit of 25%.**

However, as it turned out, **50%** of the components were **rejected.**

What is the **loss** to the manufacturer?

1. Rs. 12,000
2. Rs. 13,000
3. Rs. 14,000
4. Rs. 15,000

If possible try to explain your steps, as I have tried to solve this question several times. But failed to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's denote the cost to make the components as $C$ rupees.

With a $5\%$ failure rate, the revenue will be $(2000\times 0.95)\times 25$ rupees. If this represents a $25\%$ profit, we have
$$((2000\times 0.95)\times 25)=1.25C$$
Now we can work out $C$, which is $C=38000$.
However, $50\%$ of the components were rejected, so only $1000$ was sold at $25$ rupees, earning a revenue of only $25000$ rupees. Based on the value of $C$, can you work out how much loss was made?